# Javascript .Focus causing safari 8.1.3 to crash only on IPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari

Web App Technology: Asp.Net 4.5

The following snippet of javascript causes Safari (update 8.1.3) to crash. However it worked fine on the previous safari version. The code just resets focus to control after server request. Note: this works fine in Chrome, IE, and FF.

```
var TFoc_Id
function EndRequestHandler() {
    try {
        //Maintain vertical scroll pos in panel
        var panel = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_InputPanel1");
            if (panel != null) {
                if (typeof yPos == "number") { panel.scrollTop = yPos; }
            }
        //Reset focus to control after server request
        if (TFoc_Id != null) {
            var id = TFoc_Id;
            //Below causes Safari crash
            if (id.indexOf("ContentPlaceHolder1_") != -1) {
               document.getElementById(TFoc_Id).focus();
            }
        }
     } catch (err) {
     }
}
```

Comment: It's probably not the call to focus, but something else, it does seem like a strange piece of code, and as the arguments aren't used you probably removed quite a bit ?

Comment: @adeneo I have updated the code block to the show all code and removed the args as they were not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code to bypass the .focus for ipad's only. This is a temporary quick fix.

```
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {
            var panel = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_InputPanel1");
            if (panel != null) {
                if (typeof yPos == "number") { panel.scrollTop = yPos; }
            }

            if (MobileInfo != "iPad") {
                if (TFoc_Id != null) {
                    var id = TFoc_Id;
                    if (id.indexOf("ContentPlaceHolder1_") != -1) {
                        document.getElementById(TFoc_Id).focus();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (err) {
        }
    }

    var MobileInfo

    window.onload = function () {
        MobileInfo = get_mobile_info();
    }

    function get_mobile_info() {
        var retVal
        retVal = "";
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) { retVal = "Android" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) { retVal = "webOS" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) { retVal = "iPhone" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) { retVal = "iPad" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) { retVal = "iPod" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) { retVal = "BlackBerry" };
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) { retVal = "Windows Phone" };
        return retVal
    }
```